# Shopware6.5 App How to remove all app data permanently after app uninstall?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

My small app lacks of an option to really remove configuration settings like what did the user chooses from a select box or typed into a input text box.

I'd like to change that if the user checked the checkbox "Remove all app data permanently" when uninstall my app.

I have the manifest.xml and the config.xml (in this file I tell the Shopware system what the user can configure).

I looked into several free apps in the Shopware store, but cannot find a hint on how to do that.

Where must I tell the Shopware system to delete those settings from the database when the user is wanting that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [app lifecycle hooks](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/script-reference/script-hooks-reference#app-lifecycle) you can subscribe to using [app scripts](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts#scripts). In conjunction with the provided services, these should give you some options to react to the different lifecycle events.

However, if you should not be able to do all what you would like to do with app scripts, then, generally speaking, this shouldn't be a concern for you. As opposed to plugins which can introduce all kinds of changes programmatically, apps have to go through the provided abstraction layers. As such all changes are registered and should be able to be fully reverted on removal of an app. When data is left behind after the removal it might also not always be an oversight but could be intended depending on the kind of data. Have a look at [`AppLifecycle`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Framework/App/Lifecycle/AppLifecycle.php#L61) to examine the behavior on the different kind of lifecycle events of apps.

Comment: I will have a look into it, I have two opinions about such data, one said the app-pre test team decided not to decline a new app because of such data I'm holding, but today my app was declined because of that. In principle it is the id of the select box and text from a text box. I do not create new field or tables in the database, so I'm a bit worried about the decision that my app was declined only because that low profile data.

My opinion is, that when the user decides to uninstall the app and want to remove the data, the SQL could include a simple delete command for those data.

Comment: I don't really understand that justification either. Looking at the code, it's pretty clear that [config values are supposed to be deleted on uninstallation](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Framework/App/Lifecycle/AppLifecycle.php#L284) of the app, unless the user decides they want to keep the data. Unless I'm missing something, there should be no need for you to do anything additionally. Maybe challenge the decision by pointing that out. Could be a simple misunderstanding.

Comment: I had a look through 80 free cloud apps from the store just now, and there was 1 app who used the Resources/scripts/app-deleted method. The app is called FinSearchApp but he sets the min. version to 6.4.8.0 but when I see the reference it says min version 6.4.9.0. I wanted to have my app compatible with 6.4.0 but if I must use the app-deleted method, I must raise up to 6.4.9.0.